# Guava Cache property update on the fly

Tags: java, guava

Can I update the Guava cache properties like initialCapacity, concurrencyLevel, durationInSeconds, maximumSize etc on the fly? For example, can I update maximumSize of the cache Once the cache is already up and initialized from a program?

Answer (score 1):

No, these properties can only be set when first creating your cache via `CacheBuilder`. If you need to change the caching semantics the easiest option is to create a new cache instance and copy the contents of the old cache to the new one.